# CakePHP on subdomain

Tags: apache, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a web app built in cakePHP (1.3) working just fine for some time now. The client wanted a bunch of new features/functionality built in so I completed all that on my dev environment. I asked the host to set up "staging.domain.com" so I could upload the code and have the client review. It's on the same box just at `/var/www/staging` instead of the real app on `/var/www/html`

Here's the problem: None of the css/js/images are being pulled in.

`mod_rewrite` is on (checked) and all the defined paths seem to be correct and the app/tmp directory has permissions set to 777. I'm stumped. It's probably something simple I'm missing.

Just to be sure, I echoed out some definitions in my `default.ctp` layout file (so cake is working if it pulls that).

```
APP_DIR - app
ROOT - /var/www/staging
WEBROOT_DIR - webroot
WWW_ROOT - /var/www/staging/app/webroot/
CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH - /var/www/staging

Server[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/staging
```

Here's my `apache_get_modules`

```
Array ( [0] => core [1] => prefork [2] => http_core [3] => mod_so 
[4] => mod_auth_basic [5] => mod_auth_digest [6] => mod_authn_file 
[7] => mod_authn_alias [8] => mod_authn_anon [9] => mod_authn_dbm 
[10] => mod_authn_default [11] => mod_authz_host [12] => mod_authz_user 
[13] => mod_authz_owner [14] => mod_authz_groupfile [15] => mod_authz_dbm 
[16] => mod_authz_default [17] => util_ldap [18] => mod_authnz_ldap 
[19] => mod_include [20] => mod_log_config [21] => mod_logio [22] => mod_env 
[23] => mod_ext_filter [24] => mod_mime_magic [25] => mod_expires 
[26] => mod_deflate [27] => mod_headers [28] => mod_usertrack 
[29] => mod_setenvif [30] => mod_mime [31] => mod_dav [32] => mod_status 
[33] => mod_autoindex [34] => mod_info [35] => mod_dav_fs 
[36] => mod_vhost_alias [37] => mod_negotiation [38] => mod_dir 
[39] => mod_actions [40] => mod_speling [41] => mod_userdir [42] => mod_alias 
[43] => mod_substitute [44] => mod_rewrite [45] => mod_proxy 
[46] => mod_proxy_balancer [47] => mod_proxy_ftp [48] => mod_proxy_http 
[49] => mod_proxy_ajp [50] => mod_proxy_connect [51] => mod_cache 
[52] => mod_suexec [53] => mod_disk_cache [54] => mod_cgi [55] => mod_version 
[56] => mod_perl [57] => mod_php5 [58] => mod_python [59] => mod_ssl )
```

Anyone come across this before?

---

Update: Adding app_controller.php code per request.

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array ('Session','SparkPlug.Authsome' => 
    array('model' => 'User'));
    var $uses = array('SparkPlug.UserGroup');

    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        SparkPlugIt($this);
        $this->set('user',$this->Authsome->get());

        $user = $this->Authsome->get();
        $notificationOptions = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.id' => $user['User']['id'],
            ),
            'fields' => 'phone',
        );
        $notifications = $this->User->find('first',$notificationOptions);
        $notificationItems = count(json_decode($notifications['User']['phone']));
        $this->set('notificationItems',$notificationItems);

    }
}
```

---

### UPDATE

Thanks to those that looked into this question for me. Just received an email from my sys admin that he made a typo in the config :-/ Went to check it after and yup, all is working fine now. No amount of coding can account for that. And when you don't have direct access to the server you have to rely on other people. Anyway, maybe this question will help someone else some day.

Comment: add the code of app_controller

Comment: What does "pulled in" mean actually, are you getting 404s? Can you check apache logs along with cake's logs?

Comment: @MoyedAnsari - app_controller code added but I'm not sure it'll help.

Comment: @drHannibalLecter - by "pulled in" I mean that when I fire up the page all the cake functionality seems to be working fine. I get the view & layout I expect (code wise), it's just not showing any of the static content like a path is incorrect. e.g. If I try to open an image that should be on the page or 'browse' to the css file via URL _then_ I get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would create just a separate APP instance in your /var/html/staging/ directory - and edit your path definitions in /app/webroot/index.php to point to the cake core in /var/www/html/cake.

You can then tailor that APP dir to your preferences as needed.

Note, that this is purely for code review purposes. In no situation should you be uploading core code to production for testing!

Comment: Check out this post for more insight: http://rickguyer.com/cakephp-one-core-many-apps/